# iOS - App Rating and Reviewing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have come across a need to let users of my app to rate the app. I would have liked to give a popup with actions - either to 'Rate Now' or 'Remind Later'. My app is written using Objective-C so I was looking for related articles.

However, I came across [SKStoreReviewController API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller). Yet, after reading [this blog post](https://manuelschulze.com/en/2017/05/skstorereviewcontroller-replace-existing-rating-prompts/) and [this article](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/), it gave me the impression that Apple has restricted the prompting of this native popup to just 3 times a year.

I would like to know whether this is a restriction for all apps or is it just if you use the `SKStoreReviewController API`? And also, if there are other APIs or solutions to show the app rating such as [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate). But **iRate** has mentioned that the project is deprecated. I did not find any other useful rating engine.

Therefore, I would like to know any suggestions as to prompt app rating to the users in Objective-C.

Comment: There's a reason Apple restricts the number of times your app can show that popup, you don't want to show it too often to users because they will be annoyed and are more likely to leave negative reviews, it's a bad User Experience. I would suggest using Apple's own API. I wouldn't be surprised if they started rejecting apps that show the rate/review prompt by other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misinterpreting the "3 times per year" limit. You can call `requestReview` as many times as you want, at any time. But `SKStoreReviewController` will limit how often the review request appears. Your code is requesting a review, but `SKStoreReviewController` might deny that request. The documentation is clear that *"... this method may or may not present an alert..."*.

There's no need to track how often you have requested a review or when the most recent request was. Request at any time that makes sense, and Apple will ensure that you're not spamming your users. I've been doing this for over a year and it's worked extremely well.

Answer (score 3):

You could send them directly to the App Store to add the review, for example with a pop-up dialogue that takes them to a URL of the form:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/appId?action=write-review
```

where appId is the id of your app on the App Store. This will open the App Store at your app's page, scrolled to the section where you leave a review.

Answer (score 2):

During review stage , if review member sees any popup to review other than the new one in iOS 10.3 , the app will be rejected , on way is to make it hidden , and toggle it after review is finished say from a server variable

push app to review
   current server var is showReview = false

in code

```
 if(showReview)
 {
    // here show review popup 
 }
```

after review is finished make showReview = true , so app will fetch it and show the popup for users , this may not be the correct way , but use it if you have to

Comment: So that means I have no choice but to use the SKStoreReviewController API? And if I use any custom popup where I direct the user to the AppStore, there is a chance that my app will be rejected? Sorry for asking again. Just to clarify whether I have understood you correctly.

Comment: one way is to use the system one only , other way to create a custom popup as you want but hide it I mean in code until review is finished and app is on sale , trigger the server bool value to true to show it

Comment: Hiding something from the review team sounds like a great way to get your account canceled if they find out.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I agree , but this is the only way if he have to

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know whether this is a restriction for all apps or is it just if you use the SKStoreReviewController API?

It is not a requirement (yet), but Apple would probably say it is strongly recommended. The app I work on rolls its own "will you review my app?" functionality and we have no issues submitting and deploying to the App Store.

> Therefore, I would like to know any suggestions as to prompt app rating to the users in Objective-C.

You need to roll your own solution for asking for app reviews if you don't want to use Apple's StoreKit API.

Here are some related searches for various approaches on tackling this problem yourself:

- https://medium.com/circa/the-right-way-to-ask-users-to-review-your-app-9a32fd604fca
- https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/asking-customers-for-ratings-and-reviews-from-inside-the-app-in-ios-d85f256dd4ef

Answer (score 0):

I create by own Dialogue box where I ask user to input the ratings using the 5 star images. You can do the same.

Just create a function that check for time interval inorder to keep track when the user needs to be prompted for the review
Then Create a pop-up Subview which you can add to your apps window to ask for thier rating and a short description

Based on thier input you can use an api at your server to submit the feedback to your DB.